# Designing database for product variants

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to model product variants (not options or attributes, simply variants).

So every single variant is a product itself. The general information which is valid for all variants of a product is stored in another table (e.g.: textual description). Ok, I think that's fine and needs no further changes.

For the dependent options (e.g. color: red, size: small) I have created two variants.

**Variant 1:**

[image: diagram 1]

A Short description of the tables:

- option: stores all available options (color, size, material,...)
- value: stores all available values (red, blue, green, small, medium, large, iron, wood)
- option_value: stores all possible combinations of options and values (color: {red,blue,green}, size:{small, medium, large},...
- product_option_value now connects a product with its options (e.g.: color:red, size:small, product_id:1; color:blue, size:small, product_id:1)

Ok, I think that would work very well - on the left hand the description of the metadata (which options, which values, which combinations) for building the UI - on the right hand the linkage to the products.

But there is one problem... The possible combinations of options and values are described to build the GUI and its possible to validate it programmatically, but the database can't to the validation.

Therefore I created **variant 2:**

[image: diagram 2]

Now I'm not sure if the second solution might be the better one. What do you think? Is there room for improvement?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve with regards to data integrity and cascading updates / cascading deletes. BTW your structure looks like a light EAV model.

Comment: I was planning on expanding this comment into an answer based on the initial point: analyzing each cascading flow for both variants.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it's EAV and I'm not very happy with it, but the system will be a marketplace for many vendors. Therefore the options must be dynamic.
Regarding cascading updates / deletes: I cannot see any big differences between the two variants. Regarding data integrity, variant 2 might be better.

Comment: If there is a demand for highly dynamic structures on MySQL EAV is the only solution because DDL statements are not transactional.

Comment: MSSQL has sparse columns, PostgreSQL has its key/value store, PostgresDynamic integrates the key/value store more with a simpler syntax. And they all have transactional DDL is you would want to use good old fashioned tables created/modified on the fly.

Comment: And MySQL offers nothing of such usefull features :-/

Comment: MariaDB (MySQL fork after Oracle takeover) has some sweet new engines. For example it integrates the Sphinx Search Engine as a storage engine. But alas no dynamic key/value stores yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit `product_option_value` **only** to values that already exists in `option_value`, then yes, the second model is the better one.

However, this model allows a single value to be shared among multiple options (e.g. "red" could be both "color" and "size"). I'm guessing this is not what you wanted, in which case the model should look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Some products can consist of many parts, and every part could be colorized different. So when we have three parts, we get three color-options and every options offers the same values (colors).